# How to link libraries in MinGW without makefile or any configuration?

Tags: static-linking

I'm going to give the source code of my program which need ws2_32 library to some rookie programmers who don't know a lot about c++. So it should be as simple as possible for them. the Compiler of Visual Studio supports #pragma comment with which i can add library but I don't know what to do with other compilers like MinGW or GCC. Is there any code that I can add to my source so that the library links automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just write a makefile that pulls in all the stuff they need. Easiest for you and them I suppose.

Or is there any real reason not to handle it with makefiles? I can't imagine anything being much easier.